# How to create dynamically framelayout in linearlayout and using other xml file

Tags: java, android

I searched for a while and find no awnser and i must say that i'm very new in creating apps

i read the categorys(name, discription) from a sqlite database (i dont know how many categorys are an this database),

now i create a horizontal slider contains linearlayout(horizontal).

in this linearlayout i will create dynamically framelayout (contains custom xml code like other framelayouts, linearlayouts ect.)

i dont know how can i insert the xml ...

i hope someone can help me to find a solution for this problem

--- EDIT ---

the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int scr_w, scr_h;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    scr_w = size.x;
    scr_h = size.y;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_box_layout, null, false);

    LinearLayout llTest = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.horilila);
    //Create the Menu Boxes here
    for(int i =1;i<=6; i++){

        FrameLayout flTest = new FrameLayout(this);
        flTest.addView(v, scr_w, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        flTest.setId(i + 10);
        //Insert the new FrameLayout into the LinearLayout
        llTest.addView(flTest);

    }
}
```

the main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mailLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horilila"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

the layout for menu box, that i will insert:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fab3ff" >

        <TextView 
            android:text="This is a test..." />

    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how does the **FrameLayout** look like?

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine you have a xml, you can get a view from it like that:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_xml>, null, false);
```

Then you can add this view to your LinearLayout:

```
linearLayout.addView(v);
```